# Make string safe for file creation in Racket

Tags: scheme, racket

I have a program where the user enters a string which is used to create a file. How  can I make sure that the string is safe for file creation. One  method I thought of is:

```
(define (safestr sentstr)
   (list->string
    (remove*
     (list "|"  ";"  ":"  "/" "\\" "\'" "\"")
     (string->list sentstr) )))
```

But it does not work.

```
(println (safestr "abcd \\ \\ d /e / f | ; : d ef "))
"abcd \\ \\ d /e / f | ; : d ef "
```

What is the best way to do this?

Comment: I don't know, but if I were using this it might make more sense to convert characters like these to dashes `-` or something, rather than removing them

Comment: Is this for Windows? In Unix only the foward slash `/` is not allowed in file names.

Comment: Oh, your edit makes it a lot clearer. `string->list` returns a list of *characters*, which are different from one-character strings. So the things you are `remove*`ing need to be characters too. So instead of `"a"`, it should be `#\a` (see [Reading Characters](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/reader.html#%28part._parse-character%29) for a list that includes how to write special characters)

Comment: I think it makes more sense to refuse to create a file than to invent a new name on the user's behalf. Or even to just let the creation fail, as you need to handle failure anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is that `string->list` returns a list of characters, not of strings. Try this:

```
(define (safestr sentstr)
   (list->string
    (remove*
     (list   #\| #\;  #\:  #\/ #\\ #\' #\")
     (string->list sentstr) )))

(print (safestr "abcd \\ \\ d /e / f | ; : d ef "))

;; -> abcd   d e  f    d ef
```

You can discover this kind of things by using the interactivity of DrRacket. For instance, you see that your function `safestr` does not returns the expected result. Then you can start to try the main component of your function in the interaction window. So, in this case, you could try the first call of the function:

```
(string->list "abcd \\ \\ d /e / f | ; : d ef ")
```

to see which is its result. It shows something like:

```
'(#\a
  #\b
  #\c
  #\d
  #\space
 ... other lines missing ...
```

From which you can see immediately that the result is a list of characters, and not of strings.

This is the essence of the interactive programming style allowed by tools as the REPL environments of Lisp languages.

Another important and very useful tool is the debugger: with it you can step through the program and see the effect of each statement. In a few steps you could find the error.

In general DrRacket is a really useful IDE, and my advice is to learn at least its main features to speed up the development of your programs.

Comment: Any other character that need to be avoided? How can I only permit a to z, A to Z, 0 to 9 and space only?

Comment: @mso, for the characters to be avoided, it depends on the operating system, its version, ecc. For allowing only certain sets of characters, you can use [char-alphabetic?](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/characters.html#%28def._%28%28quote._~23~25kernel%29._char-alphabetic~3f%29%29), [char-numeric?](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/characters.html#%28def._%28%28quote._~23~25kernel%29._char-numeric~3f%29%29) etc. to filter only those characters.

Comment: Where am I wrong in regexp-match use in comments above?

Answer (score 2):

You ask:

```
How can I make sure that the string is safe for file creation.
```

The best way to do this, is to use the built-in functionality.
In particular the functions `absolute-path?` and `relative-path?` will return `#f` if the input is not a legal path.

See the [documentation](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/Manipulating_Paths.html?q=file-name#%28def._%28%28quote._~23~25kernel%29._absolute-path~3f%29%29).

Comment: Allthough `"abcd \\ \\ d /e / f | ; : d ef "` is a perfectly valid `relative-path?` in most OSes with the file `" f | ; : d ef "` residing under the two directories.